# no such table: month in "SELECT * FROM month"

Tags: flutter, sqlite

My SQLite database `bornmonth` I set up according to [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/sqlite) but when I retrieve data it says :

> SQLiteLog( 6157): (1) no such table: month in "SELECT * FROM month"

MyDB.dart

```
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

class DBProvider {
  DBProvider._();
  static final DBProvider db = DBProvider._();
}

class database{
  Future<Database> initializedDB() async {
    String path = await getDatabasesPath();
    return openDatabase(
      join(path, 'assets/database/bornmonth.db'),
    );
  }

  // retrieve data
  Future<List<bornmonth>> retrieveData() async {
    final Database db = await initializedDB();
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> queryResult = await db.query('month');
    return queryResult.map((e) => bornmonth.fromMap(e)).toList();
  }

}

class bornmonth {
  final int id;
  final String month;
  final String job;
  final String behavior;
  final String love;
  final String fate;
  final String main;
  final String beuty;
  final String power;
  final String lying;
  final String sucess;
  final String weakness;

  const bornmonth({
    required this.id,
    required this.month,
    required this.job,
    required this.behavior,
    required this.love,
    required this.fate,
    required this.main,
    required this.beuty,
    required this.lying,
    required this.power,
    required this.sucess,
    required this.weakness

  });

  bornmonth.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> result)
      : id = result["id"],
        month = result["month"],
        job = result["job"],
        beuty = result["beuty"],
        love = result["love"],
        behavior = result["behavior"],
        fate = result["fate"],
        main = result["main"],
        lying = result["lying"],
        power = result["power"],
        sucess = result["success"],
        weakness = result["weakness"];

  Map<String, Object> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'month': month,
      'job': job,
      'beuty': beuty,
      'love': love,
      'behavior': behavior,
      'main': main,
      'fate': fate,
      'lying': lying,
      'power': power,
      'weakness': weakness,
      'sucess': sucess,
    };
  }

}
```

MainTexts.dart

```
import 'package:bornmonth/MyDB.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

class maintexts extends StatelessWidget {
  final String hint;
  const maintexts({super.key, required this.hint});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: texts(hinttext: hint),
    );
  }
}

class texts extends StatefulWidget {
  final String hinttext;
  const texts({super.key, required this.hinttext});

  @override
  State<texts> createState() => _textsState();
}

class _textsState extends State<texts> {
  late database handler = database();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: MyColorsSample.primaryDark),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          ),
          title: Text(widget.hinttext, style: TextStyle(color: MyColorsSample.primaryDark),),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          elevation: 0,
          actions: [
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.copy,
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                )),
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.share,
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                )),

          ],

        ),

        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: handler.retrieveData(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<bornmonth>> snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data?.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  //read data from table month
                  return Text(snapshot.data![index].love);
                },

              );
            }else {
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
        },

        ),

        ),
      );
  }
}

class MyColorsSample {
  static const Color primary = Color(0xFF12376F);
  static const Color primaryDark = Color(0xFF0C44A3);
}
```

I tried [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/persist-data-with-sqlite-in-flutter/) with some changes but it didn't work.

Comment: You didn't create the table in your code, so error message is noraml.